# Python Pandas pivot table missing some columns after pivot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following data frame which is a rather large dataset, so for the simplicity sake I have used some of the rows and columns for illustrative purpose:

```
Group_ID  Course  Student_Number  trait_a  trait_b  trait_c  trait_d
1         0       1               1.4      2.3      3.1      4.2
1         0       2               1.3      2.2      3.6      4.1
1         0       3               1.7      2.1      3.5      4.9
1         0       4               1.8      2.2      3.2      4.0
2         3       1               1.9      2.3      3.3      4.1
2         3       2               1.2      2.9      3.5      4.1
2         3       3               1.1      2.6      3.6      4.9
3         1       1               1.0      2.0      3.7      4.3
3         1       2               1.4      2.3      3.0      4.9
3         1       3               1.3      2.6      3.6      4.1
3         1       4               1.4      2.7      3.8      4.0
4         0       1               1.6      2.8      3.9      4.8
4         0       2               1.9      2.0      3.6      4.3
5         3       1               1.3      2.3      3.6      4.2
5         3       2               1.4      2.3      3.6      4.4
5         3       3               1.1      2.1      3.6      4.9
```

I want to convert the above data frame in long format into wide format and hence I have the following code:

```
out = dataset.pivot_table(index=['Group_ID', 'Course'],
                          columns='Student_Number',
                          values=['trait_a', 'trait_b', 'trait_c', 'trait_d'])
```

Expected outcome:

```
                  trait_a             trait_b             trait_c              trait_d
   Student_Number 1    2    3    4    1    2    3    4    1    2    3    4     1    2    3    4   
Group_ID  Course    
1         0       1.4  1.3  1.7  1.8  2.3  2.2  2.1  2.2  3.1  3.6  3.5  3.2   4.2  4.1  4.9  4.0                          
2         3       1.9  1.2  1.1  NA   2.3  2.9  2.6  NA   3.3  3.5  3.6  NA    4.1  4.1  4.9  NA                                             
3         1       1.0  1.4  1.3  1.4  2.0  2.3  2.6  2.7  3.7  3.0  3.6  3.8   4.3  4.9  4.1  4.0                                              
4         0       1.6  1.9  NA   NA   2.8  2.0  NA   NA   3.9  3.6  NA   NA    4.8  4.3   NA   NA                            
5         3       1.3  1.4  1.1  NA   2.3  2.3  2.1  NA   3.6  3.6  3.6  NA    4.2  4.4   4.9  NA
```

However some of the columns are missing after missing and I got something like

```
                  trait_b             trait_c              
   Student_Number 1    2    3    4    1    2    3    4     
Group_ID  Course    
1         0       2.3  2.2  2.1  2.2  3.1  3.6  3.5  3.2
2         3       2.3  2.9  2.6  NA   3.3  3.5  3.6  NA 
3         1       2.0  2.3  2.6  2.7  3.7  3.0  3.6  3.8
4         0       2.8  2.0  NA   NA   3.9  3.6  NA   NA 
5         3       2.3  2.3  2.1  NA   3.6  3.6  3.6  NA
```

If I only pivot using `values=['trait_a', 'trait_d']` (i.e. the disappearing columns) or `values=['trait_b', 'trait_c']` (i.e. the existing columns), the pivot works fine. It's only when I mix the disappearing columns with the existing columns does this happen, so I suspect there is something incompatible between the disappearing columns and existing columns. The dataset is too large to check manually what's going wrong. Is there any general reason for this to happen and how can I check for it and solve it? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This works fine with the provided example

Comment: What is `print (dataset[['trait_a', 'trait_b', 'trait_c', 'trait_d']].dtypes)` in your real data ?

Comment: Because reason should be some columns are numeric, some strings, so `pivot_table` omit strings columns.

Comment: @jezrael Hi, I just did and I think I got it, all the disappearing columns have ``` dtype('O')``` while all the existing columns have ```dtype('int64')```. Thank you so much:).

Comment: @jezrael consider writing an answer to this question, as it solved OP's problem.